# Changes spaces in string into OR statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, replace

I am trying to convert spaces from a string into an OR statement.

```
Declare @postcodes varchar(128)
SET @postcodes = '2130 2602' --this input will be postcodes separated by a space (I'm in Australia so the postcodes are only 4 numbers long)
SET @postcodes = REPLACE(@postcodes, ' ', ' OR postcode = ') --I know this isn't right but it shows what I am trying to achieve
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE postcode = @postcodes
```

I know that the above query is really looking for users where

```
postcode = '2130 OR postcode = 2602'
```

I really want to find users where

```
postcode = '2130' OR postcode = '2602'
```

Any ideas or direction on what I should be googling?

**Update**

I ended up combining the methods suggested by [Albin Sunnanbo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/401728/albin-sunnanbo) and [Falcon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1131897/falcon). The function method suggested by [Will Hughes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/111013/will-hughes) was a lot more elegant but I would prefer not to use functions in this particular installation.

Here is my final query with some added cleaning features.

```
Declare @postcodes varchar(128)
SET @postcodes = '2130 2602 2000'

--Postcode cleaning
SET @postcodes = REPLACE(@postcodes,';',' ') --removes ";"
SET @postcodes = REPLACE(@postcodes,',',' ') --removes ","
SET @postcodes = (LTRIM(RTRIM(@postcodes))) --trim white space
SET @postcodes = REPLACE(@postcodes,'  ',' ') --removes double spaces
SET @postcodes = REPLACE(@postcodes,'  ',' ') --removes double spaces again
SET @postcodes = '''' + REPLACE(@postcodes,' ',''',''') + '''' --adds ' to @postcodes

DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(MAX);
SET @SQLString = N'
SELECT * 
FROM users
WHERE postcode IN(' + @postcodes + ')';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString;

SELECT @SQLString AS SQLString --This part serves no purpose, it just shows you what the query looks like
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't do this in the code that provides the input?

Comment: It needs to be all done in SQL because of the current setup. Doing it in the code would be a lot easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Declare @postcodes varchar(128)
SET @postcodes = '2130 2602'  
SET @postcodes = CONCAT('"',REPLACE(@postcodes, ' ', '" OR postcode = "'),'"') -- Now it will make it "2130" OR postcode = "2602"-------- 

SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE postcode = @postcodes
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, this was the simplest solution. Cheers Falcon!

Comment: Cheers back at ya mate! Always happy to help:)

Answer (score 3):

You can split strings using the answer to this [Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/314824/111013).

Having this function created, you can use it like so:

```
Declare @postcodes varchar(128)
SET @postcodes = '2130 2602'

SELECT *
FROM users
   JOIN dbo.Split(' ',@postcodes) postcodes 
   ON users.postcode = postcodes.s
```

Answer (score 2):

I would build a string and execute with sp_executesql

```
Declare @postcodes varchar(128)
SET @postcodes = '2130 2602'
SET @postcodes = REPLACE(@postcodes, ' ', ',')

DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(MAX);
SET @SQLString = N'SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE postcode IN (' + @postcodes ')';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString;
```

beware of SQL injection though.